# Apply contenttype to list in site definition

Tags: content-type, site-definition

I have a site definition in which I create 3 document libraries. I have also created 3 contenttypes which I'd like to apply to each of these libraries.

Can this be done in my Site Definition or can the contenttypes only be applied through code?

Comment: Look in to ContentTypeBindings module, or use List definitions where you add the content types to your list

Comment: @RobertLindgren Ended up making list definitions and features, worked like a charm. Post your comment as answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in to [ContentTypeBindings module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543152.aspx), or use [List definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728096%28v=office.14%29.aspx) where you add the content types to your list.

These are the no-code solutions. Of course you could also have a feature receiver or event receiver on list added that adds your content types to lists.